# Outlook IsInstantSearchEnabled Property Value Changes

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office-automation, advanced-search

I am trying to speed up my Advanced Search by using ci_phrasematch instead of the LIKE operator. ci_phrasematch can only be used if IsInstantSearchEnabled is true. If Outlook is open and running the first time my code executes IsInstantSearchEnabled = false. If I run my code again without closing Outlook the second time IsInstantSearchEnabled = true, but then my Advanced Search blows up with "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot use content indexer keywords in the restriction. Instant search is not enabled on this store.'"

My installed version is Outlook 365 using KOFF (Offline Kerio Outlook Connector) to sync with the server.

This is my first time working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. Am I missing something here?

`

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");

                if (officeType != null) //outlook is installed
                {
                    emails = new DataTable();
                    emails.Columns.Add("subject", typeof(string));
                    emails.Columns.Add("from", typeof(string));
                    emails.Columns.Add("to", typeof(string));
                    emails.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
                    emails.Columns.Add("body", typeof(string));



                    Outlook.Application outApp = null;

                    // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
                    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
                    {
                        outApp = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outApp = new Outlook.Application();
                        Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                        nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                        nameSpace = null;
                    }


                    string scope = "'" + outApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).FolderPath + "','"
                        + outApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).FolderPath + "'";

                    string email = "test@email.com";

                    string filter;

                    string contactName = GetConatactName(email);

                    if (outApp.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled)
                    {
                        if (contactName.Trim() == "")
                        {
                            filter = "(urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail = '" + email + "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > '8/1/2022')"
                                + " OR (urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto ci_phrasematch '" + email + "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date > '8/1/2022')";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filter = "(urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail = '" + email + "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > '8/1/2022')"
                                + " OR ((urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto ci_phrasematch '" + email + "' OR urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto ci_phrasematch '" + contactName + "')"
                                + " AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date > '8/1/2022')";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (contactName.Trim() == "")
                        {
                            filter = "(urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail = '" + email + "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > '8/1/2022')"
                                + " OR (urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto LIKE '%" + email + "%' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date > '8/1/2022')";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filter = "(urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail = '" + email + "' AND urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > '8/1/2022')"
                                + " OR ((urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto LIKE '%" + email + "%' OR urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto LIKE '%" + contactName + "%')"
                                + " AND urn:schemas:httpmail:date > '8/1/2022')";
                        }
                    }



                    outApp.AdvancedSearchComplete += OutApp_AdvancedSearchComplete;

                    outApp.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true, "Search");
                  }
```

Comment: Can you iust catch that particular exception and fall back to the search that does not require ci_phrasematch?

Comment: Did you connect to the existing Outlook instance or create a new one? Is it an IMAP account?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I could use a catch. I was just hoping to get  the performance of using ci_phrasematch. I don't understand why my IsInstantSearchEnabled is returning true if that is not case.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev My code will do either depending on if there is already an instance of outlook open or not.  When Outlook is closed it creates a new instance. Otherwise it using the existing one.

Comment: May the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property value depend on that?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev it seems to either way the issue still occurs. I am just not going to use `IsInstantSearchEnabled` and  `ci_phrasematch` I have looked for days and could not find anyone else who is also having the issue of  `IsInstantSearchEnabled` returning the wrong value.

Comment: Try to repair your MS Office / Outlook on the problematic machine.

Comment: Did you try to use the scanpst.exe tool to [repair the storage](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253)?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have tried both and the issue still persists.

Comment: Try to re-create a new mail profile in Outlook. Does it work?